# Возникновение названия Нидерланды

Tags: словообразование, топонимика

Почему Нидерланды так называются русскими, а не — Нидерландия, как остальные страны (провинции, области), имеющие в названии *land* (Финляндия, Исландия, Голландия и т. д.)?

Answer (score 2):

> Но на нидерландском страна называется Nederland, а не Nederlanden. То
>   есть это единственное число, верно? Откуда же взялось название Нижние
>   земли?

Не знаю, насколько корректна такая постановка вопроса, ибо обычно на все такие случае есть только Божий промысел, а не какое-то логические изыски, но сам по вопрос о законности подобной формы с филологической точки зрения вполне осмыслен. На него можно дать какое-то подобие ответа по существу.

Вся штука в том, что "land" на нидерландском означает и "страна" и "земли". Именно так, множественным числом можно перевести второе значение. Сравните: "пахотные земли", "целинные земли". То есть Nederland - это "Страна нижних земель", а не просто "нижняя страна". Эту тонкость прекрасно уловили соседи-европейцы, не только русские, но и немцы, англичане и французы называют страну формой множественного числа.

Для полноты картины: собственно на территории Королевства Нидерландов находиться лишь часть (кажется, чуть меньше половины) исторической области с названием "Нидерланды", остальная часть - это кусочки территорий современных Бельгии, Франции и даже Германии. С другой стороны, эта область составляет лишь 2/3 территории современных Нидерландов, юго-восточная и центрально-восточная часть современных Нидерландов - это довольно типичная для Европы холмистая равнина, переходящая даже в некое подобие предгорий в районе Маастрихта. Ну а третья составляющая бывшего единого королевства Нидерланды - Люксембург - это вообще отроги Альп. Так что единственное число в каком-то смысле тоже было бы оправдано. Современные Нидерданды - одна из нескольких "Нижних земель".

Что касается ссылок к Вики, то я не вижу там каких-то утверждений, с которыми я бы не согласился, но главный вопрос темы, как и когда так получилось, что исходное название страны (de Nederlanden) упростилось до единственного числа, там даже не упоминается.

Comment: Я свой вопрос снял (удалил комментарий), думаю, что разобрался. *То есть Nederland - это "Страна нижних земель", а не просто "нижняя страна".* Вот здесь точно не соглашусь. Нидерландским не владею, но посмотрев минут двадцать их Википедию, понял, что в названиях других стран/земель с множественным числом у них используется форма **Niderlanden**. Не думаю, что я ошибаюсь. А "Нижние земли" были с незапамятных времён, и оттуда так и тянется путаница.

Comment: @grizzly подождите, а с чем тут не соглашаться-то? Да, на всех языках именно так, во множественном. Кроме собственно нидерландского. Это как раз подтверждает сказанное,что *land* здесь не "страна" (как во всех ваших примерах), а именно "земли". Не по грамматике (грамматика-то единственного), но по значению.

Comment: Я не согласен с Вашим вариантом перевода с нидерландского "Страна нижних земель", а именно, с множественным числом в этом переводе. Я считаю, что переводится с единственным числом. (Здесь меня никакая правдоподобность не переубедит, только настоящий перевод.) Но в целом ответ поддерживаю, спасибо.

Comment: @grizzly У меня это не перевод, а осмысление голландского понимания. А Перевод - так вот он во всех европейских. Везде множественное. Вы с эти тоже не согласны? И вот вам косвенный аргумент https://translate.google.ru/#ru/nl/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: Хороший аргумент! Тогда не буду спорить. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Название "Нидерланды" соотносится с названием "Нижние земли", отсюда "форма множественного числа."

Этимология названия [в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B).